# Drop temporal table returns does not remove in a single query run

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I generate a SQL query on an Excel file, so I have the same tables, selects, etc. With different data as:

```
CREATE TABLE #AddressOutputInserted ([AddressId] INT)

INSERT INTO [Addresses]([AddressLine1]...)
OUTPUT inserted.AddressId INTO #AddressOutputInserted([AddressId])
VALUES('Test address'...)

//some queries here

DROP TABLE #AddressOutputInserted
```

As you can see, I created a temp table, and at the end, I removed it, then it repeated the same thing; now I want to run them in the same query as:

```
BEGIN TRAN 

  BEGIN TRY

 CREATE TABLE #... DROP TABLE #
 CREATE TABLE #... DROP TABLE #
 CREATE TABLE #... DROP TABLE #

COMMIT TRANSACTION 

 END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRAN
  END CATCH
```

When I run it throws an error:

> There is already an object named '#AddressOutputInserted' in the
> database.

I tried this with table variable as: DECLARE `@AddressOutputInserted AS TABLE(...)`
Also, with the temporal table as the example.

I noticed table variable cannot be disposed of in a single query run
but the temporal table is not working; I thought the drop table should work, but it did not; how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why would you create and drop the same table multiple times? If you want to use it again just truncate it?

Comment: Because it is autogenerated query with Excel, I can not remove it from query @DaleK

Comment: You need to change the name of the tables (for example adding number as suffix). Or you can add one additional column called partition or something else and when you insert the data to change it's value.

Comment: From [`DROP TABLE` Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks): "**Important** `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` should not be executed on the same table in the same batch. Otherwise an unexpected error may occur."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was create the table on the first query, then remove records as:

```
CREATE TABLE #AddressOutputInserted ([AddressId] INT)

INSERT INTO [Addresses]([AddressLine1]...)
OUTPUT inserted.AddressId INTO #AddressOutputInserted([AddressId])
VALUES('Test address'...)

DELETE FROM #AddressOutputInserted

INSERT INTO [Addresses]([AddressLine1]...)
OUTPUT inserted.AddressId INTO 
etcetc..
```